# CSS. Make parent have child width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have table with 700px width and row with 1400px width, so table will have horizontal scroll. How to make body element to have width same as row has?

```
<div style={{ width: 700, overflow: 'auto' }} className='table'>
    <div className='body'>
      <div style={{ width: 1400 }}  className='row' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently body has table width(which is 700px) and I can't find any way to increase it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `max-content` on the body element to take the width of its children.

```js
return (
  <div style={{ width: 700, overflow: "auto" }} className="table">
    <div
      className="body"
      style={{
        width: "max-content",
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ width: 1400 }} className="row" />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
style={{width: "fit-content"}}
```

Be sure to check its' compatibility [here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_height_fit-content).